# Where to ask questions about OpenDataCube?

Tags: discussion, scope

The [OpenDataCube](https://www.opendatacube.org/) is an [open source project](https://github.com/opendatacube/) that is aimed at making it easier to work with large volumes of earth observation data.

The ODC Steering Council is the technical governance group who lead the development of the ODC including the core [Python library](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-core) and ancillary applications, such as the [OWS engine](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-ows).

We're hoping to start using GIS Stack Exchange as the place for technical questions, so in a way, this is the first post for that. But I'm open to other suggestions.

So, where is the best place to ask a question about the Open Data Cube?

Comment: Excellent project! Would this question be better served on meta GIS SE or chat?

Comment: Meta Stack Exchange has a site-recommendations tag so I think this could have been asked there.  For now, it seems to be seeking opinions from GIS SE users as to whether such questions are on-topic here so I'm migrating it to Meta GIS SE.

Comment: Hey @PolyGeo, the question really was targetted at creating the tag and introducing a way to get ODC questions asked and answered in GIS SE.

Comment: Have no time to chat today @AlexLeith but if you have an ODC question to ask and it meets all other on-topic requirements just ask it on Main where there is an [tag:opendatacube] tag.  This one seems to be asking about whether GIS SE is the "best" place to ask ODC questions i.e. it is a Meta question about GIS SE rather than a question suitable for the Main site of GIS SE.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few avenues for help at the moment,

https://opendatacube.slack.com is pretty widely used for simple questions, but as it doesn't have premium support older messages are deleted, making it fairly transient.

https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-core/issues is good for a specific issue, especially with the Python Library itself, but it isn't suitable for requests that span several components.

I'd recommend making use of the new `opendatacube` tag on this site for generic help questions, in an effort to replace the slack chat. More specific bugs or documentation issues should be raised directly to the GitHub repository.

Comment: Would the ToS of both sides allow copying questions from slack over to stackexchange? That might be worthwhile for re-occurring questions.

Answer (score 6):

Within the Stack Exchange network the first site that I would consider for asking a question about OpenDataCube is the [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) where its [on-topic page](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says:

> If you have a question about …
>
> - ...
> - [software tools](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool-request) related to open data
> - ...
>
> … then you're in the right place!

However, by following the [software tools](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool-request) link, it seems that they may be more interested in providing [Software Recommendations](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) related to open data:

> Indicates a request for tools to create or manage open data.

Consequently, with [Remote Sensing being within our current remit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and the [Earth Science Stack Exchange](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) being less focused on software and programming than we are, I would say that the GIS Stack Exchange is currently the best Stack Exchange site for asking questions about OpenDataCube as long as they are within the scope of [our on-topic page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: as a very active open data se user, that description could use some more love; sorry about that. these questions are hard to answer because it all really just depends...some open data cube questions will definitely fit our model, some won't. i'm open to certain software questions, but i'm also not trying to debug much on that site.